# Command line arguments read from a file in VS

Tags: command-line-arguments

I write an application in C++ using VS 2022 and currently I pass some command line arguments from
`Project | Properties | Debugging -> Command Arguments.`

My question is: is it possible to have this arguments in a file and some way pass it to the VS environment?
I can do this from PowerShell command line using this:

`PS C:\> myprog.exe $(type myArgsFile.txt)`